# Difference between "governorate", "province" and "state"

Tags: meaning, differences, nouns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are: province, territory, protectorate, state…?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3572/what-are-province-territory-protectorate-state)

Canada has provinces, the US has states and Egypt has governorates.  What's the difference?

Comment: That question doesn't even mention governorates.

Comment: Please read through the answers. They are all _administrative subdivisions_ and their structure and purpose varies from country to country.

Comment: Again, it didn't mention governorates @TimLymington :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One cannot say definitively what the difference is between a province, state, or governorate because they are merely different labels for a territory within a country. Each country's administration is unique, and the label used for its subdivisions is often a matter of historical translation or other convention. In constitutional structure and political powers, a Canadian province is arguably more like a U.S. state than, for example, a province of Finland or a province of South Korea.

That said,

- *State*, when referring to a region of a country, is most commonly used for federal countries. For example, *state* is the usual translation of *land* in reference to the constituent parts of Germany and Austria. There is no hard rule— many federal states use other terms (provinces, cantons, oblasts, and so on).
- *Governorate* is the conventional translation of the Arabic *muhafazah*, and so found mostly in reference to Arab countries.

*Region* and *province* are probably the most common terms, but there are scores of different terms used for various subdivisions of various countries, which may have no basis for distinction other than custom: departments, stakes, voivodeships, et al. *Prefecture*, for instance, is a historical oddity from Portuguese traders' use of the term *prefeitura* for regions of Japan; the equivalent unit in China is usually translated as *county*. And the country that was called the United Provinces (predecessor of The Netherlands) consisted of no provinces, but "counties," "lordships", a "duchy," and a "bishopric."

Comment: The country of the United Kingdom comprises a province [Northern Ireland], a principality [Wales] and two *countries* [England and Scotland]. Perhaps we're just odd.